# Using awk if condition together with in an array condition

Tags: awk

My example goes like that:

```
 FILE_A
 ABC   spring    14    60  
 FILE_B
 ABC
```

I want to print `FILE_A` if first column matches `FILE_B` first column && second column is "spring".

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;next} ; {if ($4=="spring" && $5 in a) {print $0}' FILE_B FILE_A
```

This works fine, but if I want to add condition `if 60-(14-60)>0` I can't get it.

I tried `if ($4=="spring" && $4-($3-$4)>0 && $5 in a)`, but I can't get it work.

My question is:
**How to make `awk if` conditions with "in an array" condition?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right field numbers and leaving your boolean logic ambiguous, just use the correct field numbers and paranthesise:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} ($1 in a) && ($2=="spring") && (($4-($3-$4))>0)' FILE_B FILE_A
```

Obviously `$4-($3-$4)` can be reduced!